# Def не воспринимает больше двух аргументов (python kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

При вводе текста в `textinput` и нажатии на `plusbtn`, по идее, должна добавляться кнопка с введенным текстом, однако же пайтон выдает во такую ошибку: `TypeError: pluspress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'textinput'`. Вот текст программы:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')

class ThoughtApp(App):
    def build (self):
        base=(BoxLayout(orientation='vertical'))
        fl=FloatLayout()
        adduser=(Label(text='Добавить участника:',
        pos=(-120,360),
        font_size=22,
        bold=True,
        font_name='C:\Windows\Fonts\calibril.ttf',
        size_hint=(.6,.1)))
        fl.add_widget(adduser)
        textinput=(TextInput(multiline=False,
        pos=(225,355),
        size_hint=(.5,.15),
        font_size=16))
        fl.add_widget(textinput)
        plusbtn=(Button(size_hint=(27/800,30/800),
        text='+',
        pos=(635,366.5),
        on_press=self.pluspress,
        background_color=[.55,.55,.55,1],
        background_normal=''))
        fl.add_widget(plusbtn)
        base.add_widget(fl)
        names_gl=GridLayout(rows=1,)
        base.add_widget(names_gl)
        return base
    def pluspress(self,names_gl,textinput):
        names_gl.add_widget(Button(text=textinput.text,
        background_color=[.1,.9,.9,1],
        background_normal=''))
        textinput.text=''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThoughtApp().run()
```

Причём, я пытался менять местами `names_gl` и `textinput`, и произошла та же самая ошибка, но уже с `names_gl`. В чём причина ошибки и как исправить?

Comment: У функции pluspress должно быть только два параметра. Откуда у вас три взялось?

Comment: @nightflash не понял вопроса

Comment: Почему у функции pluspress три аргумента?

Comment: @nightflash я не вижу альтернатив. Без self конструкция не будет работать в принципе, а оставшиеся нужны для создания кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это через вызов `bind` и `lambda`:

```
def build(self):
    textinput=(...)    
    plusbtn=(Button(...))    
    names_gl=GridLayout(...)

    plusbtn.bind(on_press=lambda btn, ng=names_gl, ti=textinput: self.pluspress(ng, ti))

def pluspress(self, names_gl, textinput):
    names_gl.add_widget(Button(text=textinput.text,
        background_color=[.1,.9,.9,1],
        background_normal=''))
    textinput.text=''
```